# Import skitlean module in python with sage

Tags: python, sage

I would like to import sage and sklearn modules, but when I try to import them both sage show `ImportError`:

```
$ sage -python temp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import *
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

All sklean modules have already installed:

```
$ ipython2
In [1]: from sklearn import *
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pls.py:7: DeprecationWarning: 
This module has been moved to cross_decomposition and will be removed in 0.16
"removed in 0.16", DeprecationWarning)

$ ipython3
In [1]: from sklearn import *
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/pls.py:7: DeprecationWarning:
This module has been moved to cross_decomposition and will be removed in 0.16
"removed in 0.16", DeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet a pretty large stack of mini-donuts that you don't have it installed in your *Sage* version of Python, though.

```
$ sage -ipython
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  6 2014, 09:27:46) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from sklearn import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d78f0aaa3480> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn import *

ImportError: No module named sklearn

In [2]:
```

Assuming you already have `pip`, I would do

```
$ sage -sh

Starting subshell with Sage environment variables set.  Don't forget
to exit when you are done.  Beware:
 * Do not do anything with other copies of Sage on your system.
 * Do not use this for installing Sage packages using "sage -i" or for
   running "make" at Sage's root directory.  These should be done
   outside the Sage shell.

Bypassing shell configuration files...

Note: SAGE_ROOT=...
(sage-sh) :~$
```

and then you can install `sklearn` there.  You need to do the Sage shell command because otherwise it won't pick up the right environment variables to install it properly.  Once you've done this, though, you should be good to go.